# ASP.NET MVC: DropDownList validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-2-validation

Note: The following is just an example.

I'm pretty new to ASP.NET MVC and I'm trying to get my head around how validation of dropdown lists work. I have the following property in my `ProfileViewModel` class:

```
[DisplayName("Gender")]
public bool? Gender { get; set; }
```

`null` is meant to mean "unknown", `true` female and `false` male. In the view model constructor I

```
AllGenders = new List<SelectListItem>(2)
             {
                 new SelectListItem {Text = "Unknown", Value = "null"},
                 new SelectListItem {Text = "Male", Value = "false"},
                 new SelectListItem {Text = "Female", Value = "true"}
             };
```

First of all, it seems that I have to use strings when populating a `List<SelectListItem>`, which feels kinda weird. Is this really how it's done?

Secondly, when I choose "Unknown" in the list the validation fails telling me:

> The value 'null' is not valid for Gender.

Why is that? When I remove the "null" option and change `Gender` to a simple `bool`, everything seems fine.

This is the ASPX:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("Gender", Model.AllGenders) %>
```

(I can't get `DropDownListFor` to work correctly and it seems that many others have the same problem.)

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new SelectListItem {Text = "Unknown", Value = "null"},
```

should be:

```
new SelectListItem {Text = "Unknown", Value = ""},
```

Posting "" will result in null being bound.

Comment: Thanks a *lot*, I never would have been able to figure that out. Did you learn this by trial and error or can I find that information somewhere? It seems that "go-to resources" are pretty scarce when it comes to ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Nope, never read about that, made sense to me.  I think I first noticed it leaving input type=texboxs empty.  The model binder always bound the string fields to null.